# Ошибка соединения с сервером 1С Предприятия 8.2

Tags: 1с, сервер, sql-server, windows-server

Добрый день.

Мои действия:

1. Поставил ОС Windows Server 2003.
2. Поставил MSSQL 2005.
3. Установил 1С Предприятие 8.2 (установил все что предлагало - сервер, расширения...) правда выдало ошибку, но тем не менее установило. Кажется, ошибка была связана с сервером предприятия.
   3.1. В MSSQL создал пустую базу.
4. Узнал имя сервера и его порт (SUPERCOMPUTER/1433)
5. В програме  1СV8 Servers добавил свой сервер. Нажал кнопку "обновить" и получил ошибку:

> "Ошибка соединения с сервером 1С предприятия 8.2. ..."
>
> Сервер недоступне(не отвечает, завершается аварийно или порт занят другим приложением) line=607 file=SrcDataExchangeTcpClientImpl.cpp

Как обойти ошибку ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как узнали порт - 1433? Какая версия SQL Server'а? 
Попробуйте телнетом постучаться на сервер на этот порт, если все правильно, телнет должен подключиться.

Comment: а как это сделать?
точнее, какой командой ? в винде справка по телнету плохая.

MS SQL 2005.
Порт узнал из SQL Server Configuration Manager - в свойствах TCP/IP

Comment: пишу в "cmd":  telnet whitepanter. Получаю ответ "23: Сбой подключения"

Comment: telnet whitepanter.local - дает ошибку "неудалось открыть подключение к этому узлу на порт 23". 

Если укзываю в конце строки порт (любой) - пишеь "сбой подключения"

Comment: telnet whitepanter 1433 - так попробуйте. Это подключение на определенный порт, который вас интересует.